# $scope is not defined for angular inject dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I use the last version of angularjs(1.3.3):

I use 3 javascript libs

```
<script src="framework/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="framework/tm.pagination.js" ></script>
```

My javascript code is:

```
    angular.module('myApp', ['tm.pagination']).controller('testController', [function($scope, $http){
    var reGetProducts = function(){

        var postData = {
            currentPage: $scope.paginationConf.currentPage,
            itemsPerPage: $scope.paginationConf.itemsPerPage
        };


        // console.log(postData);
        $http.get('data/mybook.json').success(function(data){

            $scope.paginationConf.totalItems = data.total;

            $scope.products = data.items;
        });
    };


    $scope.paginationConf = {     
        currentPage: 1,
        itemsPerPage: 15      //the problem emit here and problem is $scope is undefined
    };

    $scope.$watch('paginationConf.currentPage + paginationConf.itemsPerPage', reGetProducts);
}]);
```

The error is:

```
error: $scope is undefined @http://localhost:8080/table.html:55:13 invoke@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:4129:14 $ControllerProvider/this.$get</</<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:8370:11 nodeLinkFn/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:7618:13 forEach@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:330:11 nodeLinkFn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:7617:11 compositeLinkFn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:7003:13 compositeLinkFn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:7006:13 publicLinkFn@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:6882:30 bootstrapApply/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:1439:11 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:14204:16 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:14302:18 bootstrapApply@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:1437:9 invoke@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:4129:14 bootstrap/doBootstrap@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:1435:1 bootstrap@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:1455:1 angularInit@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:1349:5 @https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js:25746:5 jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://localhost:8080/framework/jquery-1.9.1.js:1037:10 jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://localhost:8080/framework/jquery-1.9.1.js:1148:7 .ready@http://localhost:8080/framework/jquery-1.9.1.js:433:1 completed@http://localhost:8080/framework/jquery-1.9.1.js:103:4
```

I think I already declare $scope when I inject the variable.

Comment: the controller function should not go in an array, the array before the function is to list un-minified formal parameter names. use the formal param of "$scope" and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have left out $scope in your declaration (before it's injected as a parameter):

```
angular.module('myApp', ['tm.pagination']).controller('testController', [
    '$scope', 
    function($scope, $http){

        //...the rest of your code...

    }]);
```